# Deleting rows from multiple table in different schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have different schemas in my database and each schema has a minimum of two tables, and each table contains one column name, `data`. Now I want to delete all the entries from different tables present in the different schemas where `data = 'test'`.

Below is my database structure

```
A schema - a table - data column
           b table - data column
B schema - c table - data column
           d table
```

How can delete the row and which approach needs to be followed to handle this deletion in a single query or store procedure?

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. It can also easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. I've removed the spammed tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag appropriately.

Comment: Also, what is a "bale"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the all schemas ,table names with column names in the same database

with the following query ,in general it will list all tables and views ,
so filtered with
is_updatable='YES'(y bcoz u can update only table columns).

with the below query export the list to a text file and execute it .

```
SELECT 'delete from  '||table_catalog||'.'||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' where '||column_name||' = ''test'';'
FROM information_schema.columns where "column_name"='data' and is_updatable='YES';
```

create a procedure and run it with cursor

```
 FOR CUR_REC IN (
 SELECT 'delete from  '||table_catalog||'.'||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' where '||column_name||' = ''test'';' as delcmd
FROM information_schema.columns where "column_name"='data' and is_updatable='YES'
) LOOP
                        EXECUTE CUR_REC.delcmd  ;
                  END LOOP;
```

with this cursor loop you can get the list and delete .

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how I can execute this listed query in one go, as I need to call one API whose responsibility is to run this query  and delete the records from the table. with this I am able to get the delete query list only

Comment: create a procedure with the cursor loop and execute it